# Ethernet adapter with static IP configuration not accessible on start up

Tags: windows-7, static-ip, gigabit-ethernet

My home workstation motherboard has two Ethernet adapters. Both ports connect to the same local network and Internet router. The only difference is one is set as DHCP while the other has a static IP configuration.

In recent weeks, I don't really know when it began to be a problem, the adapter with the static IP address won't be able to configure itself properly on system start up (stuck with one of those automatic IPv4 addresses with /16 subnet mask). I just have to manually disable and enable the adapter before it can complete its IP configuration and recognise the network it's residing; no configuration value change.

What factors can cause the adapter to stall its static configuration?

On fresh start up

```
Ethernet adapter Top Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCI GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 90-E6-BA-1E-70-D8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b024:6058:b813:c33e%9(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.195.62(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 361817786
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-37-4F-6B-90-E6-BA-1E-70-D8

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 165.21.100.88
                                       165.21.83.88
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

After disabling/enabling

```
Ethernet adapter Top Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCI GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 90-E6-BA-1E-70-D8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b024:6058:b813:c33e%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 361817786
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-18-37-4F-6B-90-E6-BA-1E-70-D8

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 165.21.100.88
                                       165.21.83.88
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Comment: Generally you only get the automatic IP when DHCP fails to get you a new lease.  If it's actually set static, it shouldn't change.  Could things to try:  Have you tried setting it to a different IP address and see if it behaves any differently? Does it behave the same way in Safe Mode with Networking?

Comment: Perhaps edit your question and post the result of an `ipconfig` for the network connection in question, so we can see how it's currently set.

Comment: I have added in the ipconfig to show the state it gets itself into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why, but if both adapters are manually configured with static IP addresses, they get their settings on system start up and able to sense the network they're in with Internet connectivity.